# Laravel 3 how to include variables in flash message url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have a form which is used to write to a database. I managed to successfully complete everything except including php variables as part of the url in the flash message:

```
if($sale->save() && $updateowed)
        {

            return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_notice','Sale record id '.$sale->id.' created. <a href=/printmemo/'.$sale->id.'>Print Cash Memo</a>');

        }
```

The first $sale->id is displayed correctly. However, the $sale->id inside the href prevents the form form redirecting to '/' and shows a blank message. Checking the database reveals the $sale->save() is indeed successful. I kind of know it's the problem with how I use quotes, however I'm unable to solve the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you should only pass the data to the session and build the tag from your view, for example you may pass the `$sale->id` form the controller using something like this:

```
return Redirect::to('/')->with('sale_id', $sale->id);
```

Then in your view where you want to show the link using `$sale->id` build it like:

```
<?php if(Session::has('sale_id')): ?>
    <a href=<?php echo "printmemo/" . $sale->id ?>>Print Cash Memo</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you are using `Blade` then use blade syntax to echo the `id`.